# Opencv, figuring out the type of a pixel at compile time

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

tl;dr; how do I get the compile-time pixel type from `cv::Mat my_mat = cv::imread("myfile.png")`?

I have a function that I've written, that takes in a Mat iterator:

```
template <typename RAI>
void my_func(RAI mat_begin, RAI mat_end) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RAI>::value_type T;
    do_stuff<T>(*mat_begin);
}

int main() {
    cv::Mat my_image = cv::imread("my_file");
    my_func(my_image.begin(), my_image.end());  
}
```

I can use this function without explicitly stating what `RAI` is, because I think the compiler is able to figure out what it is at compile time.

It has turned out that I need to refactor this to take in the whole `Mat`.  However, now I can't figure out how to call `do_stuff<T>`, because I don't know how to figure out what `T` is except from `iterator_traits` of my matrix iterator type, and I don't know how to figure out the compile-time matrix-iterator type from my code, since the matrix is gotten with an `imread`, which seems to set the type for pixels at run time, somehow, magically.

Comment: my_mat.type() will give you the OpenCV encoding of the type. You would need a switch-case to call your function with the proper built-in type. Tl;dr; the default for imread is CV_8UC3

Comment: Btw, tl;dr; should be put at the top ;)

Comment: but my_mat.type() is a runtime type?  Somehow the compiler must be figuring out the appropriate types at compile time, because the provided example works correctly....

Comment: Yes, runtime. If you want to know the type at compile time (usually preferred) use Mat_<t>, and its typedef. Eg: a Mat of runtime type CV_8UC3, at compile time is Mat_<Vec3b>, aka Mat3b

Comment: So `cv::imread` is compile-time deciding to read in my image as a `Vec3b`?  That would explain things...

Comment: "[flags] >0 Return a 3-channel color image."... default is 1...  https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread

Comment: But `C++: Mat imread(const string& filename, int flags=1 )`, flags is set run-time, so it is not known compile-time what the pixel type will be....

Comment: Just discovered that my `do_stuff<T>` function fails when `T` is a `Vec3b`, so `imread` must not be giving me `Vec3b`s...

Comment: From the beginning... A "Mat" is an object which doesn't know the type it's containing. That's why you need to use things like "m.at<double>". You can know, however it's opencv type, e.g. CV64FC1. A "Mat_<T>" is a different object (very similar to a "Mat") where the type is defined at compile time. With imread you can do "Mat3b img = imread("...");" to get a compile time type = Vec3b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenCV` queries the `Mat.type()` value to determine the underlying pixel type and then uses an if or switch statement to invoke a particular template specialization.

For instance, here are a few snippets from `floodfill.cpp` in `imgproc/src/floodfill.cpp`

```
Mat img = _image.getMat();
...
int type = img.type();
...
if( type == CV_8UC1 )
    floodFillGrad_CnIR<uchar, uchar, int, Diff8uC1>(
            img, mask, seedPoint, nv_buf.b[0], newMaskVal,
            Diff8uC1(ld_buf.b[0], ud_buf.b[0]),
            &comp, flags, &buffer);
else if( type == CV_8UC3 )
    floodFillGrad_CnIR<Vec3b, uchar, Vec3i, Diff8uC3>(
            img, mask, seedPoint, Vec3b(nv_buf.b), newMaskVal,
            Diff8uC3(ld_buf.b, ud_buf.b),
            &comp, flags, &buffer);
else if( type == CV_16UC1 )
    floodFillGrad_CnIR<unsigned short, uchar, int, Diff16uC1>(
            img, mask, seedPoint, nv_buf.s[0], newMaskVal,
            Diff16uC1(ld_buf.s[0], ud_buf.s[0]),
            &comp, flags, &buffer);
else if( type == CV_32SC1 )
    floodFillGrad_CnIR<int, uchar, int, Diff32sC1>(
            img, mask, seedPoint, nv_buf.i[0], newMaskVal,
            Diff32sC1(ld_buf.i[0], ud_buf.i[0]),
            &comp, flags, &buffer);
else if( type == CV_32SC3 )
    floodFillGrad_CnIR<Vec3i, uchar, Vec3i, Diff32sC3>(
            img, mask, seedPoint, Vec3i(nv_buf.i), newMaskVal,
            Diff32sC3(ld_buf.i, ud_buf.i),
            &comp, flags, &buffer);
else if( type == CV_32FC1 )
    floodFillGrad_CnIR<float, uchar, float, Diff32fC1>(
            img, mask, seedPoint, nv_buf.f[0], newMaskVal,
            Diff32fC1(ld_buf.f[0], ud_buf.f[0]),
            &comp, flags, &buffer);
else if( type == CV_32FC3 )
    floodFillGrad_CnIR<Vec3f, uchar, Vec3f, Diff32fC3>(
            img, mask, seedPoint, Vec3f(nv_buf.f), newMaskVal,
            Diff32fC3(ld_buf.f, ud_buf.f),
            &comp, flags, &buffer);
else
    CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "");
```